# Cron arbtirary weekdays range

Tags: cron

In crontab I can set this syntax `5 4 * * 3-5`

Which translates to every Wednesday, Thursday and Friday at 4:05, which works well, but when using `5-3` which (expected) translates to Friday, Saturday...Wednesday, it says wrong syntax, I noticed it should be in order, but what if I need it the other way?

I use [this](https://crontab.guru) to test cron syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way is

```
5 4 * * 0-3,5-7 script
```

- 0 and 7 are sunday

another way

```
5 4 * * 0,1,2,3,5,6 script
```